# python coding, strings more digits than letters

Tags: string, xcode, input, comparison

please help!

how do I write a program that answers the question to my string, "are there more than digits than numbers" I've tried a few things, and searched the internet with no luck.

Thank you
Andrew

as you can, I don't know what i;m doing lol